# Linux kernel insmod failed with error Invalid parameters

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have a simple kernel module and want to define an IRQ. If I call in the code the following function, the module can not be inserted:

```
   result = request_irq(12,     
                        test_irq,  
                        0,   
                        "testgpio", 
                        NULL);
```

This is the error from insmod:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gpioc.ko: Invalid parameters
```

The hardware is a RPI 4 with 2 GB and Ubuntu 64Bit.

```
static irqreturn_t test_irq(int irq, void *data)
{
    /*interrupt-handling*/

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

@I tried this to get the irq number but without success:

```
  struct gpio_desc *gpio = NULL;
   gpio = gpiod_get(NULL, "SPI_CE0_N", GPIOD_OUT_HIGH);
    if (NULL == gpio){
      printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: invalid GPIO16\n");
      return -ENODEV;
   }

   int n = gpiod_to_irq(gpio);
    if (n <= 0){
      printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: invalid IRQ\n");
      return -ENODEV;
   }
```

It is not clear to use the function "gpiod_get". Here especially the first parameter!

Does anyone know where a working example exists?

Comment: How do you insert the module ? The command line ?

Comment: sudo insmod gpioc.ko

Comment: Do you have any message in kernel log : result of "dmesg" command ?

Comment: GPIO_TEST: The interrupt request result is: -22

Comment: Could you share the content of /proc/interrupts ?

Comment: According to this [link](https://support.criticallink.com/redmine/boards/10/topics/2094), you may need to call gpio_to_irq() to get a soft irq number.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you get **EINVAL** error from *request_irq()* according to the comments. The requested IRQ may not be correct. For GPIO, you may need to use [*gpio_to_irq()*](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/gpio-linux-device-driver-using-raspberry-pi/) function to get the IRQ associated to a given GPIO.

The [GPIO documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/) documentation provides the pin to GPIO number. The latter is passed to *gpio_to_irq()* to get the IRQ.

Comment: Tnx, how do I get the parameter for gpiod_to_irq. I read the docs but this isnt clear to me.  Tried: gpio = gpiod_get(NULL, "SPI_CE0_N", GPIOD_OUT_HIGH);

Comment: I updated the answer to get the IRQ from the pins.

Comment: If think you mean this "GPIO with C/C++ using standard kernel interface via libgpiod" but couldnt find the code. The problem is only with using gpiolib in Kernel mode not in the User land.

Comment: It is in Linux kernel. Look at this example (in french but the example program is in english): https://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2014/01/22/gpio-du-raspberry-pi-mesure-de-frequence/
Another example : https://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2017/06/06/kernel-interruptions-et-tasklets/

Comment: Sorry, but the code use GPIO and not GPIOLib.The point is that gpiolib use the device tree.